# Copy range to new worksheet and keep colours of cells and graphs

Tags: excel, vba

I created an investment analysis workbook. The results are summarized within an overview/dashboard.

The macro then copies the specified cell range (dashboard range), creates a new worksheet and pastes the dashboard on the new sheet. All works ok.

However, the **color scheme of the cells and copied graphs change**.

Which command enables to "lock/fix" the colours of a cell before copying/pasting it and that integrates with an existing sub()?

Comment: Can you [show us your macro](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58658293/edit)?

Comment: which of them you try? 
[XlPasteType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpastetype?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_XlPasteType_xlPasteColumnWidths)

Answer (score 0):

You can paste in different ways in vba with `.Pastespecial xlPaste-`.

Here are a few options that might work in your case:

`xlPasteAllExceptBorders` which will paste your cell value or formula, the formatting, the background colour, all but the borders. Most likely useful in your case.

`xlPasteValues` pastes only the value of the cell (not the formula creating the value), none of the formatting.

`xlPasteFormats` pastes only the current formatting of the cell, including background colours and borders, but no values or text.

[And many more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This should already work. 

Would this also work if I would copy the entire worksheet instead of a specified cell range? To "copy" worksheet format settings to the newly created one

Comment: Yes it would, but instead of copying the entire worksheet, I suggest using `.Usedrange.copy` instead, so you only copy the used range which will be a lot less intense than copying the entire sheet. Special pasting this to cell A1 on the other sheet should do the trick.